# Set up Asp.Net Site on Amazon Server

Tags: amazon-web-services

> I want to know how can i set up my Sitecore Asp.Net Site on Amazon
>   Client has given the credentials for Amazon server. How can i set up my sitecore asp.net website on Amazon Server?

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad. If you score a "pay as you go plan up front" it can be adjusted based on needs. Moving through the actual wizards to create account and tokens is easy/peasy. You would probably prefer a Windows 2012 server with IIS7.5

From there its just a measurement of use between request and responses. If you are not in need of a sql server database then you should be good.

I spun up my friends kids a MineCraft server for his friends to connect. It took about 30 minutes and the kids were quite for 4 days :) while on vacation.